# 14.10 Cannot ping www.google.com

Tags: networking, dns, 14.10, ping

I have a relatively fresh install of ubuntu 14.10. I am currently not able to `ping www.google.com` but I can successfully do `ping 8.8.8.8` and I can successfully ssh into the machine from another computer on the network. I have tried removing/reinstall resolvconf with `sudo apt-get remove --purge resolvconf && sudo apt-get install --reinstall resolvconf`. The caveat here is that I can't resolve DNS so the re-install doesn't work. I checked out https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/resolvconf/+bug/1308378 and tried pulling down the deb and doing the instructions listed there but I still cannot resolve any hosts. I have also tried editing /etc/resolv.conf and adding `nameserver 8.8.8.8`.

I haven't found any other solutions. The only other software I have installed is webmin, does anyone know of webmin causing issues?

Some additional information:

cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
         dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

cat /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Flush all the entries in the iptables using the below command

iptables --flush

After this try to ping www.google.com

Comment: Hmm! quiet strange. If you've internet access you should be able to ping public IP's. Without a proper DNS server, I doubt an FQDN will resolve. Are you using a static IP configured or through a DHCP? would like to see more information on those as well to assist further.

Comment: IP configured through DHCP however I did try changing it to a manually configured address to be sure. I can ping ip addresses fine but cannot resolve DNS entries for some reason. @vembutech there were no entries in the iptables so flushing didnt have any resolve the issue.

Comment: Just to make sure that you're on the right track.. could you please post the output for `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: @AzkerM updated the question above with the information.

Comment: Have you tried using the sutomatic (default) network configuration, or creating a new one if you don't have it?  Perhaps you didn't enter the information correctly for DNS servers

Comment: try with mentioning entries like this` nameserver 8.8.8.8 ` <press enter> and again `nameserver 8.8.4.4` and one more thing I wanna know , do you have any local DNS server ?

Comment: I just used the default network configuration that was setup when ubuntu was installed. I will try to add the second nameserver entry when I get home. I do not have any local DNS server. All of the other machines I have on the network, admittedly OSX, do not have any DNS overrides set for them and work fine. @AgentCool

Comment: Seems like OP is adding DNS server to his loopback interface and not is actual physical NIC that is connected to his network

Answer (score 1):

Why are you putting the dns-nameserver on the loopback interface and not the physical interface which is connected to your network?

Here is what I have for one of my interfaces

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 11.0.0.13
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 11.0.0.0
        broadcast 11.0.0.255
        gateway 11.0.0.1
        dns-nameservers 11.0.0.7 8.8.8.8
```

If you need step by step instructions, check out this article http://uglyvpn.com/2015/03/16/how-to-install-owncloud-on-ubuntu-14-10-using-hyper-v-part-3-of-3/